# Why is the tkraise() in raiseFrame() not working?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk



class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,windowTitle,size):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(windowTitle)
        self.geometry(f"{size[0]}x{size[1]}")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=True)
        #init function to set attributes to the window

    def createWidgets(self):
        #function to set the widgets the window has
        self.datFrame = dataEntryFrame(self)
        self.datFrame.createFrame()
        self.menuFrame = menuFrame(self)
        self.menuFrame.createFrame()

    def raiseFrame(self):
        self.datFrame.tkraise()

    def createWindow(self):
        #function to display the window
        self.mainloop()

    def collectInfo():
        
        pass



#creates the frame containing the data entry form
class dataEntryFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.config(width = 760, height = 800, bg = "red")

    def createFrame(self):

        self.__title = labelBox(self, 28, "Sign Up", 0, 0)
        self.__title.config(font = "Helvetica 35 underline")


        self.__nameLabel = labelBox(self, 28, "Name: ", 2, 0)
        self.__nameEntry = entryBox(self, 20, 28, 2, 1)

        self.__emailLabel = labelBox(self, 28, "Email: ", 4, 0)
        self.__emailEntry = entryBox(self, 20, 28, 4, 1)

        self.__budgetLabel = labelBox(self, 28, "Budget:      $", 6, 0)
        self.__budgetEntry = entryBox(self, 20, 28, 6 ,1)

        self.__ageLabel = labelBox(self, 28, "Age: ", 8, 0)
        self.__ageEntry = entryBox(self, 20, 28, 8, 1)

        self.__weightLabel = labelBox(self, 28, "Weight: ", 10, 0)
        self.__weightEntry = entryBox(self, 20, 28, 10, 1)
        self.__weightUnitLabel = labelBox(self, 28, "kg", 10, 2)

        self.__heightLabel = labelBox(self, 28, "Height: ", 12, 0)
        self.__heightEntry = entryBox(self, 20, 28, 12, 1)
        self.__heightUnitLabel = labelBox(self, 28, "cm", 12, 2)

        self.__button = tk.Button(self, command = self.getInfo, height = 0, width = 8, text = "Sign Up", font = ("",35))
        self.__button.grid(row = 13, column = 0)


        self.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    def getInfo(self):
        name = self.__nameEntry.get()
        email = self.__emailEntry.get()
        budget = self.__budgetEntry.get()
        age = self.__budgetEntry.get()
        weight = self.__weightEntry.get()
        height = self.__heightEntry.get()
        print(name, email, budget, age, weight, height)
        


#generating an entry box is made into a class as it is repeatedly used
class entryBox(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, widthSize, fontSize, rowVar, colVar):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.config(width = widthSize, font = ("", fontSize))
        self.grid(row = rowVar, column = colVar, sticky = "W", pady = (0, 10))



#generating an label box is made into a class as it is repeatedly used
class labelBox(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, fontSize, textVar, rowVar, colVar):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.config(text = textVar, font = ("", fontSize))
        self.grid(row = rowVar, column = colVar, sticky = "W", pady = (0, 10))



class menuFrame(dataEntryFrame):

     def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.config(width = 760, height = 800, bg = "blue")

     def createFrame(self):

        self.__button = tk.Button(self
                                  ##, command = self.getInfo
                                  , height = 0, width = 8, text = "Sign Up", font = ("",35))
        self.__button.pack(pady = 10)

        self.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "news")


onlyWindow = Window("Login / Sign Up", (760,870))
onlyWindow.createWidgets()
onlyWindow.createWindow()
sleep(2)
onlyWindow.raiseFrame()
```

I tried using sleep and running it to see changes, but after 2 seconds the dataEntryFrame coloured in red doesn't appear on top of menuFrame coloured in blue. I cannot see what's the problem as the frames, the frames are the same sizes also.

the contents within the createFrame functions can be ignored, I think only the **init** of each class matters

Comment: I think I found the issue, but I am not sure. Is the issue due to the fact that I'm running a method outside of mainloop(), and because of that the changes are not visible?